# Form data not passing to database on clicking save

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Currently I have an edit page where any changes I make are reflected in my database. But one part of my form is not sending the data which is the notes tab where if there is no notes, the user can add a new note to the database, or if a note already exists, then they should be able to edit it. Currently this is my code:

View Class:

```
<div id="notes-wrap">
<table id="tableobj1">
    <thead>
      <tr class="active">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th nowrap>Added By</th>
        <th colspan="2" nowrap>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="objrows1" class="tblerow1">
        <td colspan="3"><textarea name="note" class="form-control notes" placeholder="Notes"></textarea></td>
        <td colspan="2" width="1%"><button type="submit" class="btn-sm savenotes" data-href="<?php echo site_url('contacts/savenotes/'.$leadid); ?>" >
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      <?php if($notes) foreach($notes as $val):?>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo($val['added_date']);?></td>
        <td width="75%" class="textnote"><?php echo nl2br($val['note']) ?></td>
        <td width="15%"><small><?php echo $val['display_name'] ?></small></td>
        <td width="1%" align="center"><a><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a><a data-url="<?php echo site_url('contacts/updatenote/'.$val['notes_id']) ?>" style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a></td>
        <td width="1%" valign="middle" align="center"><a data-url="<?php echo site_url('contacts/deletenote/'.$val['notes_id']) ?>" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach;  ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-light">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#notes-wrap").on("click", "button.savenotes", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        saveleadnotes($(this)); 
    });

    $("#tableobj1").on("click", "tbody a.remove", function(e) {
        var $t=$(this).closest ('tr');$u = $(this).data('url');  
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-warning',
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            closeOnConfirm: true
        }, function (e) { 
            if($u && e){
                removeobj($u); 
                $t.remove();
            } 
            else if(e){ 
                $t.remove(); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 

    function saveleadnotes(obj){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: obj.data('href'),
            async:false,
            type:"post",
            data:obj.closest('.tblerow1').find(':input').serialize(),
            success: function(result){ 
                if(result<1)        
                {
                    obj.closest('.tblerow1').find('[name="note"]').focus(); 
                }
                else {
                    leadnotesdocs('<?php echo site_url('contacts/notes/'.$contact->id); ?>','#notes-wrap'); 
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Controller Class:

```
function edit($id,$return=0)
    {
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $edit['notes']= $this->contacts_model->load_notes($id); 
            $edit['leadid']= $id; 
        } else {
            $maindata=array('agents_id'=>$this->input->post('agents_id'));
            $updated=$this->contacts_model->update($maindata,$id); 
            if($updated){
                if($this->input->post('notes')){ 
                    foreach($this->input->post('notes') as $key => $note):  
                        if($note !='')  {
                            $smdata = array('contacts_id'=>$id,'note'=>$note,'added_by'=>$this->session->userdata('clientsessuserid'));   
                            $this->contacts_model->save_notes($smdata); }
                    endforeach;
                }
     }

    public function updatenote($id){
        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $maindata = array('note'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('leadnote')));   
            $insid= $this->contacts_model->update_notes($maindata,array('notes_id'=>$id)); 
            $c= $this->contacts_model->load($id,"refno");
            $this->contacts_model->saveactivity(array('object_ref'=>$c->refno,'object_id'=>$insid,'activity'=>'Note Updated','action'=>'Updated'));  
            echo $insid;exit; 
        } 
    }

   public function savenotes($id){
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        $maindata = array('contacts_id'=>$id,'note'=>$this->input->post('note'),'added_by'=>$this->session->userdata('clientsessuserid'));   
        $insid= $this->contacts_model->save_notes($maindata); 
        $contacts= $this->contacts_model->load($id,"refno");
        $this->contacts_model->saveactivity(array('object_ref'=>$contacts->refno,'object_id'=>$insid,'activity'=>'Note Added','action'=>'Added'));   
        echo $insid;exit; 
     } 
}
```

Model Class:

```
 function save_notes($maindata){
    $this->db->insert("crm_contacts_notes",$maindata); 
    return $this->db->insert_id(); 
}
function load($id)
{
    $id=$this->db->escape_str($id);
    $cond=array('id'=>$id);
    $this->db->where($cond);
    $this->db->from("crm_contacts");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
 function update_notes($maindata,$cond){
    return $this->db->update("crm_contacts_notes",$maindata,$cond);  
}
```

But doing so just refreshes the page whenever I click on the save button and nothing is sent to my database. I cannot even see if any requests are being made since whenever I click the save button, the page refreshes.

Comment: You have a syntax error in `e.preventDefault(),saveleadnotes($(this));`. You should separate the two expressions with a `;`, not a `,`. And unless you intend for this button to submit a form, change `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"` and you won't need `e.preventDefault()`. And as a general suggestion, you should format your code in a sensible way. Be consistent with code indention and stick to one expression per row. It will make your code _way_ easier to read and debug (and to find typos like the one I pointed out)

Comment: Inside this `$("#notes-wrap").on("click", "button.savenotes", function(e){...}`. Are you sure that this event triggered. It seems that when you click save then it start from this. Try to `e.preventDefault();` and then `console.log(e);` or do some alert to make sure that this event is working. However, I don't see any `notes-wrap` id anywhere.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so I changed my `,` to `;` and replaced submit as button, but now when I click on the button then nothing happens, there is no AJAX call as well in my console.

Comment: @vee so I tried to add an alert code below `e.preventDefault();` and it didn't return any output when I clicked on it.

Comment: @H2O This means your event listener `$("#notes-wrap").on("click", ...)` is not working. As I said before... I don't see HTML `id="notes-wrap"` anywhere (before your last edit). This event start listening from this `id`. Since your last edit, this `id` is already exists. Try to debug again if this event listener is working.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors, but before you click the button and after (which you can see now when you've changed the type to "button" instead of "submit")

Comment: Yes I did check my console for any errors and it doesn't output anything when it is button or submit

Comment: Close your `<div id="notes-wrap">` with `</div>` properly and try again to make sure that the event listener that I was mentioned before is really working. It's look like start from that point.